# halacha of reporting a Jew to the (non-jewish) authorities

Tags: halacha

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what are the limits of “mesira”?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6260/what-are-the-limits-of-mesira)

What is the halacha regarding reporting a jewish person to non-jewish police/authorities? Does the nature of the crime in question (child abuse versus theft) play a role?

Comment: I assume you mean in a place where a beit din exists and where no mandatory-reporting laws apply?

Comment: @MonicaCellio those kinds of parameters should probably be outlined in an answer, I intentionally left this open-ended.