# Is a Jew allowed to plead guilty?

Tags: mesirah

One of the most objectionable acts a Jew can do to another Jew is to inform on him to the government.

[Punishment for mesirah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/67159/punishment-for-mesirah/67181#67181)

This is most serious and can lose you Olam Habah:

> Maimonides further explains: "It is forbidden to hand over a Jew to
>   the heathen, neither his person nor his goods, even if he is wicked
>   and a sinner, even if he causes distress and pain to fellow-Jews.
>   Whoever hands over a Jew to the heathen has no part in the next world.
>   It is permitted to kill a moser (informant) wherever he is. It is even
>   permitted to kill him before he has handed over (a fellow Jew)."

When someone pleads guilty, he is telling the government that he did a crime. In exchange for this, he will benefit (reduced sentence).

Is it relevant that the Jew being informed upon is the same Jew that is doing the informing? After all, we know that one is not permitted to murder himself.

Comment: By pleading guilty, the accused is aiming on receiving a reduced sentence. The authorities already have him. If his position were so easy to get out of, he wouldn't plead guilty :) Are you talking about simply turning oneself in out of some ethical remorse?

Comment: Note that the bounds of mesirah are a bit more complex.