# Calling the Police on a fellow Jew in the United States

Tags: halacha, contemporary-halacha

Is it halachically permissible for a Jew to call the police on a fellow Jew if a person is threatened with imminent violence in the United States. I know there is an issue with informing on a fellow Jew and I was wondering how this pertains to this.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6260/759

Comment: IMHO, there’s an important distinction in this practice between the ancient world and today's reality: back then the society was largely tribalized and there was a clear separation between "us Jews" and "them, gentiles", because the ancient police weren't democratized, they only represented the ruler,  so the idea of "Mesira" described transfer of a Jew to foreign control. In our countries, the police is a social construct, something like "Tuvey Ha'ir", people's representatives, so there's no "Mesirah" per ce.

Answer (score 1):

The sefer "Making It Work" has a full chapter on mesira (chapter 20). In it, R' Ari Wasserman lays outs the guidelines very clearly about what is, and is not, a problem of mesira. I recommend his work highly.

On Pg. 387 he writes:

> Rav Yaakov Bloy write that if there is no other way to pretect
> oneself, it is permitted to call the police without first turning to a
> beis din under any of the following circumstances: if one is being
> attacked; if he has reasonable grounds to suspect that he is going ot
> be attacked; and certainly, if he has received threats against his
> life or safety. This is true, says Rav Bloy, even if the assailant
> will be fined or imprisoned as a result (Pischei Choshen, Lichos
> Nezikin, Chapt. 4, footnote 18)